# Cannot migrate sqlite3 to postgres in rails using taps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to migrate my rails database from sqlite3 to postgresql so I can push to heroku. I'm trying to migrate the data as well.
Here is my gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'taps', '>= 0.3.22'
gem "tilt", '~> 1.4.1'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do

    gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'sqlite3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
end
gem "sequel_pg", :require=>'sequel'
group :production do

    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'puma'

end
```

I also changed my database.yml file to migrate to postgres

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_development
  pool: 5
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_test
  pool: 5
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_production
  pool: 5 
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost
```

I ran the following command to start my taps server and it started correctly:

```
taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 sam pass -p $PORT
```

In a different terminal I ran:

```
sudo taps pull postgres://sam:pass@localhost/gainxp_development http://sam:pass@localhost:$PORT
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "gainxp_development" does not exist
```

My pg_hba.conf file is the following

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

I've been at this for weeks trying to migrate my db. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of what the problem or solution could be, but I'd say you try the following:

1. In your Gemfile add `gem 'pg'`
2. run `bundle install`
3. run `rake db:setup` and `rake db:migrate`
4. run the `taps` commands

Comment: I already have postgres in the gemfile under sequel_pg and when I run rake db:setup I get PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "gainxp_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'

Comment: my question might sound bit silly but, Does your postgres user has a database creation permission?

Comment: I'm sure but if you're able to log into your postgres using  a super role, you could do: `ALTER USER sam CREATEDB;` reference: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33285/granting-a-user-account-permission-to-create-databases-in-postgresql

Comment: I did that and now I get: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
: CREATE DATABASE "gainxp_development" ENCODING = 'utf8'

Comment: I've never had to deal with encoding issues, all I've had was: [adapter, pool, timeout, database, [template]]. Also, you should remove the password and username field for production as Heroku would often provide a ENV['DATABASE_URL'] that would be used by your application

Comment: I fixed this by using this: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/dataerror-new-encoding-utf8-is-incompatible-with-the-encoding-of-the-template-database-sql-ascii-52124

Comment: But when I try to migrate the database I get this error: 
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "city" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "listings" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_602015426d"
FOREIGN KEY ("city_id")
  REFERENCES "city" ("id")

Comment: The migration file in question is this one: class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    
    add_reference :listings, :city, index: true
    add_foreign_key :listings, :city
  end
end

Comment: You should be able to fix that either by changing `add_foreign_key :listings, :city` to `add_foreign_key :listings, :cities` or by removing the foreign_key reference

Comment: Now when I run `taps pull postgres://sam:pass@localhost/gainxp_development http://sam:pass@$IP:$PORT ` I get `Failed to connect to database:
  NoMethodError -> undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s`